# How to create a heatmap in angularjs

Tags: angularjs, google-chrome, heatmap

How to create a `heatmap` using a `angularjs` plugin ?

I need to run the heatmap in my google chrome browser. Please help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Highcharts with angularjs to generate heatmap

```
<script src="http://code.highcharts.com/stock/highstock.js"></script> 
<script src="http://code.highcharts.com/modules/heatmap.js"></script>
<div id="container" style="height: 400px; min-width: 310px; max-width: 800px; margin: 0 auto"></div>
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.7.2/highcharts/highcharts/tree/master/samples/highcharts/demo/heatmap/)**

Comment: Thanks alot for your answer Sajeetharan. Is it possible to use Geographical map ? I need to show heatmap data in like google map.

Comment: you can use this directive https://github.com/shekhargulati/angular-cal-heatmap-directive

Comment: heat map should be based on the latitude/longitude.

Comment: I found it. Thanks a lot for your time. :)

Comment: how to do that ?